# Scanner: How do I limit the Scanner input after n characters?

Tags: java, string, substring, java.util.scanner

How do I limit the user's input `str = key.next();` after n characters? I'd like that `str` should only hold a specific amount of characters. I am very new to programming, and any help would be appreciated.

```
        String str;
        int k;
        int n =1000;
        String min="";
        String max="";

        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        str = key.next();
        k = key.nextInt();

        max = str.substring(0,k);
        min = str.substring(0,k);

        for (int i=0; i<str.length()-k+1; i++){

            if (str.substring(i, i+k).compareTo(max)>0){
                max = str.substring(i, i+k);
            }

            else if (str.substring(i, i+k).compareTo(min)<0){
                min = str.substring(i, i+k);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(min + "\n" + max);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix for you is to get a substring of the returned input string that is at most n characters long:

```
if (str.length() > n) {
  str.substring(0, n+1);
}
```

Where n is the max length you want str to be. This code snippet would go after `str = key.next();`

Note that `String.substring` is inclusive for the beginning index but exclusive for the ending index.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass `System.in` directly, but pass a wrapper to `System.in` implementing `InputStream`. In this wrapper, you can easily limit the number of characters you return.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regular expression to the method `next(String pattern)` (or perhaps `findInLine(String)`). For example:

```
str = key.next(".{10}");
```

will put the next 10 characters into `str`.